# ignore values below threshold in adjacency matrix for heatmaps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, gplots

I have an adjacency matrix (netm) with co-occurrences as mostly 0's. I get the heatmap below when I plot it using:

```
require(gplots)
heatmap.2(netm,col=c("gold", "dark orange","orange","yellow"),
    Rowv=F, Colv=F, dendrogram="none", scale="none", trace="none")
```

How can I ignore values below a certain threshold in the matrix? I don't want to plot values below 3 in my graph co-occurrence matrix.

[image]

Snapshot of data (a co occurence matrix )

```
    bacardi breezer aldi    rum white   coconut
bacardi 0   2   0   1   0   0
breezer 2   0   0   0   0   0
aldi    0   0   0   1   1   0
rum 1   0   1   0   1   1
white   0   0   1   1   0   0
coconut 0   0   0   1   0   0
drinks  0   0   0   1   0   1
daniel  0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Is this correctly tagged `ggplot2`? Where is the `heatmap.2` function from? Can you give us a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269?

Comment: @axeman Its from package gplots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can substitute `NA` to unwanted values (e.g. 0s), and keep them in the plot:

```
netm2 <- netm
netm2[netm2 == 0] <- NA
heatmap.2(netm2, col=c("gold", "dark orange","orange","yellow"), Rowv=F, Colv=F, dendrogram="none", scale="none", trace="none")
```

or manually remove columns/rows which contain `NA`s:

```
netm3 <- netm2[complete.cases(netm2), complete.cases(t(netm2))]
heatmap.2(netm3, col=c("gold", "dark orange","orange","yellow"), Rowv=F, Colv=F, dendrogram="none", scale="none", trace="none")
```

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo , My heatmap looks better :-)